# how to convert 1154 time format in 11:54 in pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
slno  time
0     1154
1       1634
2       1902
3       1533
4        946
5       1832
6       1517
7        758
8       1625
9       1223
10      1658
11      2143
12      1248
13      1106
14      1310
15      1709
16      1546
17      1720
18      1555
19      1110
20      1711
21       915
22      1621
23      1656
24      1052
25      1643
26      2011
27      1859
28      1315
```

Comment: Isn't this merely a text formatting problem?  https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting

Answer (score 3):

Using `to_datetime` with `strftime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df.time,format='%H%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
Out[235]: 
0     11:54
1     16:34
2     19:02
3     15:33
4     09:46
5     18:32
6     15:17
7     07:58
8     16:25
9     12:23
10    16:58
11    21:43
12    12:48
13    11:06
14    13:10
15    17:09
16    15:46
17    17:20
18    15:55
19    11:10
20    17:11
21    09:15
22    16:21
23    16:56
24    10:52
25    16:43
26    20:11
27    18:59
28    13:15
Name: time, dtype: object
```